# cast array[string] to array[float] in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My Dataframes current prinSchema looks like this:

```
root
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- val: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I would like to convert the `val` column to an array type holding float values, and I used

`df = df.withColumn("val", col("val").cast("array<float>"))`

But it make my `val` column null.

What could be the right way of doing this?

Comment: could you add your sample input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to first convert the string values to float values before casting to an array of floats.  Maybe something like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, transform

df = df.withColumn("val", transform(col("val"), lambda x: x.cast("float")))
df = df.withColumn("val", col("val").cast("array<float>"))
```